# Iterative algorithm to draw an ellipse on sphere

Tags: algorithms, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

I am trying to understand a formula in the [`drawEllipse`](https://api.kde.org/stable/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/GeoPainter_8cpp_source.html#l00289) function of `KDE Marble`. This function draws an ellipse, given a center and height and width (in degrees). The algorithm draws upper and lower halves of the ellipse by constructing 2 polygons. Each of the polygons have `precision` number of points. Larger precision results in more precise ellipse formation. It iterates $t\in [0\dots p]$ where $p$ is the precision. For each such $t$ it creates a latitude longitude pair $(\phi(t), \lambda(t))$. Then it joins all these coordinates to form a polygon.

$$\phi(t) = \phi\pm\frac{h}{2}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}$$
$$\lambda(t) = \lambda+\frac{w}{2}t$$

Where $\phi$ and $\lambda$ are the latitude and longitude of the center. $h, w$ are width and height of the ellipse expressed in degrees. I don't understand why this works. I am trying to find a reference to this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I created the source code in question. 
The drawEllipse method just draws an ellipse in carthesian coordinates, so on a sphere it will look skewed and will not resemble a real ellipse (unless the extent is very very small).

The formula used there is just the regular formula for an ellipse.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation